# Eclipse - Javascript and JSTL in the same page won't validate

Tags: javascript, eclipse, validation, jstl

I have code like follows in a .jsp page:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js">
    var TextFields = new Array();

    $(document).ready(function() {
        <c:if test="${fn:length(textProperties) > 0}">
            <c:forEach var="i" begin="0" end="${fn:length(textProperties) - 1}" step="1">
                TextFields[${i}] = "${textProperties[i]}";
            </c:forEach>
        </c:if>
```

I am receiving red all over my JSTL code, because it is trying to interpret it as javascript.  Is there a way of getting the editor to recognise both the javascript and JSTL seperately, such as a configuration in my project or a plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to the top of your JSP page

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1" %>
```

If you're still having issues, did you create your eclipse project as a "Web Project"? It should work with your default Eclipse settings.

Comment: This does not work.  Yes I did, if my page just contains jstl validation works, and if it just contains javascript validation works.  It is only when I do a combination of both that there is problem.